# Symfony best way to store search parameters set by a form

Tags: forms, symfony, session

I'm looking for the best way to store parameters set by a form.

The form is generated by an external controller called in my base.html.twig

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeBundle:FooFilter:index', {'originalRequest': app.request })) }}
```

I tried to store the form posted datas in the session.

My goal is to use these parameters in others controllers to filter my sql queries. But when I'm try to use the params stored in session there are not updated until the request completly done.

What is the best way to dynamically store parameters from a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the treatment on the form in the controller method called with the route.

You should separate `AcmeBundle:FooFilter:index` in 2 methods, like `AcmeBundle:FooFilter:pre_index` and `AcmeBundle:FooFilter:index`.

`AcmeBundle:FooFilter:pre_index` should be static, so you can call `AcmeBundle:FooFilter:pre_index(app.request);` in the other controllers, in order to update the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: I don't understand your method. Can you explain me what is the role of indexAction?

Comment: in index action you render your form. you don't have to manipulate $_SESSION in AcmeBundle:FooFilter:index since you call it from a view.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand! So where I manipulate the session? And how I "call" my form from base.html.twig?